# encoding problems writing UTF-8 SQL statements to a local file

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing SQL to a file on a server this way:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('translate.sql',mode='a',encoding='utf8',errors='strict')
```

and then writing SQL statements like this:

```
query = (u"""INSERT INTO story_question_response
        (group_id, story_id, question_id, answer )
        VALUES
        (%s,@last_story_id,%s,'%s');
        """ % (kw.get('to'), lookup.get(q), kw.get(q)))
f.write(query)
```

I have confirmed that the text was okay when I pulled it. Here is the data from the dictionary (kw) passed out to a webpage:

```
46:埼玉県
47:熊谷市
42:お散歩デモ
```

It appears correct (I want it to be utf8 escaped).
But the file.write output is garbage (encoding problems):

```
INSERT INTO story_question_response
            (group_id, story_id, question_id, answer )
            VALUES
            (279,@last_story_id,62,'ãã©ã³ãã£ã¢ããã'); )
            /* updating the story text on old story_id */
UPDATE story_question_response
    SET answer = 'å¤§å­¦ã®ãã­ã·ã§ã¯ãã¦å­¦çãæ¬å¤§éç½ã®è¢«ç½å°(å²©æçã®å¤§è¹æ¸¡å¸)ã«æ´¾é£ãããããã¦ã¯ç¾å°ã®å¤ç¥­ãã®ãæ$
    WHERE story_id = 65591
    AND question_id = 41
    AND group_id = 276;
```

using an explicit decode gives an error:

```
f.write(query.decode('utf8'))
```

I don't know what else to try.

Question: What am I doing wrong, in writing a utf8 file?

Comment: What does `print repr(kw.get('q'))` give you? I want to know the type *before* it is being interpolated.

Comment: How are you loading the webpage? Are you using BeautifulSoup, urllib2, or other tools? Something is scrambling encodings here.

Comment: When you say "the file.write output is garbage", how are you viewing the file? If you save a file as valid UTF-8, then view it in a CP1252 text editor, it's going to look like garbage…

Comment: Meanwhile, `f.write(query.decode('utf8'))` is obviously not going to help. `query` is `unicode`, to decode it from UTF-8, Python first has to encode it to something (and by default it will use `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is probably `'ascii'`) that it can then decode. You probably wanted `query.encode` here, not `.decode`. But you don't want that either, because `file` is a UTF-8 `codecs` file.

Comment: Could you update your examples of text from the webpage and bits of the sql file to show sections that cover the same data?

Comment: Unrelated to encoding problem, but related to SQL, you should probably escape the values you insert into SQL string to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I was using NANO editor on a server / linux machine - which is usually UTF-8 friendly. NANO FAQ says "In version 1.3.12 or later, Unicode should be usable. With your terminal, locale (LC_ALL and similar environment variables), and encoding configured to properly support UTF-8, you should be able to enter and save Unicode text."

Comment: Interesting -- maybe the file was encoded fine, and nano was displaying it correctly, but putty's emulation was latin1 screwing it up. I've switched my SSH terminal to UTF8 and now I see a bunch of boxes on nano instead of garbled accented a's and e's... but pasting into stackoverflow comment gives me japanese -- see this: '利益を得るのにふさわしい人達'

Comment: seems like windows won't display the japanese characters (just boxes) unless I install another language  -- but as far as I can tell the characters are encoded. My next test will have to be to insert this statement into the database and use phpmyadmin to confirm that it is still japanese.

Comment: FWIW @MartijnPieters the output from repr(kw.get('q')) is well-formed UTF8 codepoint: u'\u5229\u76ca\u3092\u5f97\u308b\u306e\u306b\u3075\u3055\u308f\u3057\u3044\u4eba\u9054' so the garbling is happening at the terminal editor / viewer and on my english-only windows OS, even though Notepad++ says it is reading in UTF8 no BOM.

Comment: @MarcMaxson: Those aren't "UTF8 codepoints". In fact, there is no such thing. Those are _Unicode_ codepoints. UTF-8 is a byte-string representation of Unicode, where the codepoint `\u5229` is represented as the bytes `'\xe5\x88\xa9'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have enough information to be sure, but I'd give decent odds that your file is actually perfectly valid UTF-8, and you're just viewing it as if it were something else.

For example, on Windows, if you open a file in Notepad, by default, it will only treat it as UTF-8 if it starts with a UTF-8 BOM (which no valid file ever should, but Microsoft likes them anyway); otherwise, it will treat it as whatever your default code page is. Which is probably some Latin-1 derivative like CP1252.

So, your string of kana and kanji ends up encoded as a bunch of three-byte UTF-8 sequences like `'\xe6\xad\xa9'`. Then, that gets displayed in Notepad as whatever each of those bytes happen to mean in CP1252, like `æ­©` (note that there's an invisible character between the two visible ones).

---

As a general rule, whenever you see weirdly-accented versions of lowercase A and E every 2 or 3 characters, that almost always means you've interpreted some CJK UTF-8 as some Latin-1-derived character set, because [UTF-8 uses `\xE3` through `\xED` as the prefix bytes for most CJK characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout), and [Latin-1 has accented lowercase A and E characters in that range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1#Codepage_layout). (Similarly, weirdly-accented capital A versions usually mean European or symbolic UTF-8 interpreted as Latin-1, especially when you've got stray `Â`s inserted into what looks like otherwise valid or almost-valid European text. If you look at the charts, you should be able to tell why.)

Comment: The sample garbage is not CP1252; decoding it from CP1252, encoding to Latin1 then decoding from UTF8 doesn't produce anything readable either, because CP1252 is rather close to Latin1.

Comment: It looks a lot more like SHIFT-JIS, actually.

Comment: Probably not Shift-JIS, the output doesn't make sense (from what I know about Katakana).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't want to go through every character set in the world and figure out which one would produce this mojibake; the point is that he's almost certainly viewing it in some character set other than UTF-8, and the fix is to just view it as UTF-8 (which is what it is).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Also, you're taking his CP1252 mojibake, copying it from a UTF-8 browser page and pasting it into a UTF-8 console. You can't then decode that as CP1252 and get anything reasonable. You can get _closer_ by _encoding_ it as CP1252, then decoding as UTF-8 (or just printing to a UTF-8 console), but it will likely only work for a few characters before you run into a problem where an invisible character got lost in the copy-paste…

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Actually, instead of guessing, I should have just tried it… If you take his "answer" string as Unicode, then encode it as CP1252, it is definitely valid UTF-8 for Japanese but with some invisible characters missing. It starts off with 大学, then there's clearly a missing byte in the middle of the next character. The most commonly lost invisible character from CP1252 mojibake is `'\xad'`; the only question is whether it's the second or third byte in the sequence. And the same is true from there on out.

Comment: This answer was correct -- specifically -- I tried various ways of seeing the translate.sql file output. NANO editor on putty-ssh (even when set to utf8) does not display the japanese on a windows machine UNLESS japanese language support is installed. Likewise, downloading the file and viewing in notepad++ (set to use utf8 encoding) displays boxes instead of japanese characters -- for the same reason. But pasting the output into this comment box on stackoverflow, or into a trello card, or into a phpmyadmin SQL box yields the right characters, and datbase update is correct.

Comment: @MarcMaxson: At least viewing it as UTF-8 without Japanese support shows you that there are characters you can't display, instead of silently interpreting it as garbage like you get by viewing it as CP1252… Anyway, if it works in a browser, you must have some Japanese-capable font installed, it's just that your default monospace font isn't Japanese-capable without Japanese support. So, if you can't install Japanese support, you might be able to work around it by switching the font in PuTTY, Notepad++, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is utf8, you should probably use the following code to generate the query:

```
query = (u"""INSERT INTO story_question_response
        (group_id, story_id, question_id, answer )
        VALUES
        (%s,@last_story_id,%s,'%s');
        """ % (kw.get('to').decode('utf8'), lookup.get(q).decode('utf8'), kw.get(q).decode('utf8')))
```

I would also suggest trying to output the contents of kw and lookup to some log file to debug this issue.

You should use encode on objects of class unicode, and decode on objects of class str in python.

You should escape any string you insert into SQL statement to prevent nasty SQL injections.

The code above doesn't include such escaping, so be careful.

Comment: I will test this 'query' with the .decode('utf8') and report. however, I treid very similar things today and they generated errors - reading up suggests that I was decoding UTF8 twice.

Comment: This wasn't the problem - it was a windows no-language support issue (even when a program decodes UTF8 correctly, windows cannot display the japanese characters)